# CSS sticky position não funciona com Bootstrap class=row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Salve, salve.

Estou com problemas para fixar um menu num website.
Quando o conteúdo da página tem uma DIV com class bootstarp ROW, esta DIV sobrescreve o menu na hora da rolagem.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<main class="main-container">
  <h4>
  Scroll page down to see the HEADER fixed on top
  </h4>
  <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="main-content">
    <h4>MAIN CONTENT TITLE</h4>
    <div class="row"><!-- if delete this DIV, works fine -->
      <div class="col">
        left col
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        right col
      </div>
    </div><!-- row -->
  </div><!-- main-content -->
  <footer class="main-footer">FOOTER</footer>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.main-container{ max-width:600px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 10px green; padding:10px; margin-top:40px;}
.main-container *{padding:10px;background:#aaa; border:dashed 5px #000;}
.main-container * + *{margin-top:20px;}
.main-header{ height:50px; background:#aaa; border-color:red;}
.main-content{ min-height:1000px;}
.main-header{position:-webkit-sticky; position:sticky; top:0;}
```

EXEMPLO:
https://jsfiddle.net/WRobynson/qhdfbjmv/10/

Alguém tem uma ideia pra ajudar?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é um problema de z-index, junto com o `positio:sticky` vc tem que declarar um `z-indez > 1`, isso vai resolver o problema. Tipo como o código abaixo

```
.main-header{position:-webkit-sticky; position:sticky; top:0; z-index:10}
```

Para ver funcionando execute o código abaixo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
    .main-container {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: solid 10px green;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .main-container * {
        padding: 10px;
        background: #aaa;
        border: dashed 5px #000;
    }

    .main-container * + * {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .main-header {
        height: 50px;
        background: #aaa;
        border-color: red;
    }

    .main-content {
        min-height: 1000px;
    }

    .main-header {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <main class="main-container">
        <h4>
            Scroll page down to see the HEADER fixed on top
        </h4>
        <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
        <div class="main-content">
            <h4>MAIN CONTENT TITLE</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- if delete this DIV, works fine -->
                <div class="col">
                    left col
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    right col
                </div>
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div><!-- main-content -->
        <footer class="main-footer">FOOTER</footer>
    </main>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado, Hugo. Abraço.

Comment: @WalterRobynson legal que resolver ai, se vc acredita que a pergunta foi resolvida considere marca-la com um clique no  `✔` que fica logo abaixo das setinhas ao lado ra resposta. Valeu a força, sucesso!